# Discriminator value is from another table

Tags: java, hibernate

So I'm very new to hibernate and wanted to know if it was possible to have a discriminator value be of another table so I have 3 tables named Vehicles, BikeLots and BikeTypes. I want to map Vehicle based on the BikeType with my tables looking like this:

Vehicles (VehicleId, SerialNumber, BikeLotId, Point)

BikeLots( BikeLotId, DeliveryDate,  BikeTypeId)

BikeTypes( BikeTypeId, BikeTypeDescription )

is it possible to map a vehicle to being Dock or Dockless based on the BikeTypeId ?
currently my classes look like this

```
@Entity(name = "Vehicles")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorFormula("CASE ?")
public abstract class Vehicle {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private short vehicleId;

  @Column(columnDefinition = "nvarchar(50)")
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private String serialNumber;

  private Point point;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "BikeLotId")
  private Bikelot bikeLot;
}
```

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Dockless")
public class DocklessVehicle extends Vehicle{
// valid code
}
```

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Dock")
public class DockVehicle extends Vehicle {
}
```

If there is anything more I need to provide or clarify let me know since this is the first question I'm asking here.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, but I really wouldn't recommend you to do this as it is not very efficient.

```
@DiscriminatorFormula("case (select bikeLot.BikeTypeId from BikeLots bikeLot where bikeLot.BikeLotId = BikeLotId) when 1 then 'Dock' when 2 then 'Dockless' else null end")
```